# How do i create ActionBar Transparent

Tags: android, android-actionbar, navbar

http://www.mediafire.com/view/?wfua11aiand93a5

I upload a photo to meadiafire.

I  want to create the Actionbar and Navbar Visible and how can I create my layout under the status bar but I don't find any way.

Maybe its a simple question but I don't know what to do.

Comment: May try this way https://github.com/ManuelPeinado/FadingActionBar

Comment: What about bottom navbar and how to show full screen without removing status bae

Comment: Use Sticky Immersion
https://developer.android.com/training/system-ui/immersive.html#sticky

Comment: Yes and thankyou can you please help me to creatd transparent action bar

Comment: set actionbar color - Color.Transparent.

Answer (score 0):

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    this.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    setContentView(R.layout.login_layout);
```

> use this hide action bar and create custum action bar which u can tranparent and design as u want 
>   and set alpha like this

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="#ffffff"
tools:context="com.Test.webview.MainActivity" >

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:alpha="0.5"
    android:background="#000000" >
</LinearLayout>
```